# Необходима помощь по замыканиям.

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Прохожу учебник по JS на известном сайте, и вроде я понял замыкания, осознал.
Но...
Вот решение к заданию:

1. Создайте функцию `filter(arr, func)`, которая получает массив `arr` и
   возвращает новый, в который входят только те элементы `arr`, для
   которых `func` возвращает `true`.
2. Создайте набор «готовых фильтров»: `inBetween(a,b)` – «между `a`,`b`», `inArray([...])` – "в массиве `[...]`". Использование должно быть таким:

Я хоть убейте второй день не могу понять откуда `inBetween` берет **a** и **b**,
это функция вроде создана в другом `lexical environment`.

В общем объясните, чтобы до меня дошло. Почему это работает?

```
function filter(arr, func) {
  var result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var val = arr[i];
    if (func(val)) {
      result.push(val);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

function inBetween(a, b) {
    return function(x) {
      return x >= a && x <= b;
    };
  }

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
alert( filter(arr, inBetween(3, 6)) ); // 3,4,5,6
```

Comment: Или дайте ссылку где можно почитать более понятным языком об этом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как функция-замыкание inBetween() возвращает новую функцию, то для наглядности подставим код этой самой новой функции вместо её вызова здесь:

```
                             a  b
alert( filter(arr, inBetween(3, 6)) );
```

Получим такой код, где вместо a и b соответственно аргументы 3 и 6:

```
alert( filter(arr, function(x) {
    return x >= 3 && x <= 6;
  })
);
```

Ну а дальше просто происходит вызов этой функции для каждого элемента массива, где выполняется проверка на принадлежность диапазону [3,6]:

```
if (func(val)) {
  result.push(val);
}
```